# ESLint complains that SvelteKit's App namespace is not defined

Tags: typescript, eslint, sveltekit

In my `+error.svelte` page I want to import a component, and then pass in the error object.

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from "$app/stores";
  const error = $page.error;
</script>

<RenderError {error} />
```

In my component, I have this simple variable which triggers an error in eslint:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let error: App.Error;
</script>
```

Error: `'App' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)`

But the `App` namespace is global, right? How do I get rid of this error?

My `app.d.ts` file:

```js
declare global {
  namespace App {
    interface Error {
      errorId?: string;
    }
    // interface Locals {}
    // interface PageData {}
    // interface Platform {}
  }
}
 
export {};
```

Comment: The code does not show how you import type definitions for `App`. Can you edit and clarify your question?

Comment: How am I supposed to import that type definition? It's just inside of `app.d.ts`.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: You don't need to reference `global` declarations explicitly.

Comment: Interesting. But then the question is how can `eslint` pick it up - it is probably missing in some piece of config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed temporally by adding the `App` namespace as an `eslint` global.

.eslintrc

```json
{
  //...
  "root": true,
  "globals": {
    "App": "writable"
  }
}
```